# Generating a Table of Tables with R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, xtable

In part of an assignment, I am outputting 14 tables (expected to use a particular package to generate them rather than just table) and they are all relatively small. It'd be nice to output them in 3 columns, for example, but can't find anything that would achieve that. The below is my code that I'm using to output the tables (have changed variable names to generic placeholders).

```
obj <- tapply(geno, INDEX=index, summary)
for (name in names(obj)) {
  print(xtable(obj[[name]]$table, caption=name))
}
```

The package being used is the `genetics` package and the tables are of genetic frequencies. As requested, the `dput` of one of the tables is

```
structure(c(55, 50, 14, 0.46218487394958, 0.420168067226891, 
0.117647058823529), .Dim = c(3L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("C/C",  "C/T", "T/T"), c("Count", "Proportion")))
```

Is there a way to achieve this kind of formatting with R Markdown?

Comment: You'll make it much easier for people to help you, and will be more likely to get useful answers, if you provide the `obj` object that goes into your `xtable` code. If that's too big, at least provide one element of `obj`; for example, paste into your question the output of `dput(obj[[1]]$table)`.

Comment: I have attempted to update appropriately, my only concern was not wanting to post my actual answer to the assignment question